# Why does my .icns icon not work with QT/C++ on OSX?

Tags: c++, qt

I made a small app that simulates a magic 8-ball in C++ using QT Creator for OSX. I set `ICON += 8ball.icns` in the `.pro` file and ran qmake through QT Creator. My app works, but it doesn't have an icon in Finder view or in the Dock. I've tried every tutorial/StackOverflow post about my problem, but I can't seem to get the icon to work. Any thoughts?

Edit, .plist file:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
   <string>Magic8Ball</string>
   <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
   <string>8ball.icns</string>
   <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.yourcompany.Magic8Ball</string>
   <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
   <string>ContentCanvas</string>
   <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
   <string>APPL</string>
   <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
   <string>????</string>
   <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
   <string>10.13</string>
   <key>NOTE</key>
   <string>This file was generated by Qt/QMake.</string>
   <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
   <string>NSApplication</string>
   <key>NSSupportsAutomaticGraphicsSwitching</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you follow this https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-macos? How did you create the icns file?

Comment: please show a [mre]. Have you checked the generated plist?

Comment: Yes, I followed the doc example. The .plist file has been added to my answer.

Comment: @LucaCarlon, I made the 32x32 icns file from a png with the ImageMagick command-line tool.